# Jquery onclick function not firing sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function

Here you can see my code:

```
$(window).on('click touchstart', '#includeDevices a', function (e) {
            if ($(this).children('p').hasClass('selected')) {
                $(this).children('p').removeClass('selected');
                $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $(this).children('p').addClass('selected');
                $(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
            }
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        });
```

Need a little help maybe full remake of this code I don't know.
The code simply just gives a class to each the clicked **a** in HTML.
If the function runs it will have by the class another color.

The code seems simply but not working on my phone.
Working on another phones and sometimes not working on laptops.
Error code is not given in console just simply not working.

The point is I need a fully functioning function for my interface which is not doing problems caused by another platforms like mobile device or tablet device or laptop or PC. I need it working anytime and always. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you pinpointed if the issue is related to the compatibility of the web browser with the `on('touchstart')`? It sometimes happens that the issue is that safari or firefox do not trigger the same events that chrome does , and different mobile devices trigger different events

Comment: Could you please list the platforms on which the code is not working, instead of "_my phone_" and listing some platforms it is working on ..?

Comment: Android 8.0, windows and just Google Chrome mobile and Google Chrome on PC. Don't use Safari of course I will but just in case my program works on Chrome so I can test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to iOS, not Android, I notice non-clicking behavior if the anchor element doesn't have href attribute looks like this:

`<a ...></a>`
instead of
`<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>`

Just put some value in href attribute, doesn't matter if you override it.